# how to add extra information in every row of autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am doing autocomplete of venues from all over the world and it is working fine but now I want the address of that particular venue to be in the next line of venue name.

if my autocomplete is reading venue name as ABCD, then below the ABCD it should be the address of this venue. I can return the address of venue but have no idea how to place it here.

my javaScript

```
$("#venueName").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function(request, response) {

    var city_lat = $('#city_lat').val();
    var city_lon = $('#city_lon').val();

    request.call = "auto_poi_ugc";
    request.cityid = $('#eventCityId').val();
    request.lat = city_lat;
    request.lon = city_lon;

    setTimeout(function() {
      ajax_req = $.ajax({
        url: "/ajaxcalls",
        dataType: "json",
        data: request,
        success: function( data ) {    
            data.splice(venue_limit,data.length);
            response( data );
        }
      });
      }, 700);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {

        if(ui.item.value == "Loading..."){
          return false;
        }
        if(ajax_req != undefined)
        {
            ajax_req.abort();
        }
        if(ui.item.value != '')
        {
            $('#venue_latitude').val(ui.item.latitude);
            $('#venue_longitude').val(ui.item.longitude);
            $('#primus_id').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#event_venue_add').val(ui.item.add);
        }
     },
    search: function(event, ui) {
        if($(this).hasClass('error-border')){
            $(this).removeClass('error-border');
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding autocomplete into it.

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    if(item.add == undefined){
        item.add = "";
    }
    return $( "<li>" ).append( "<div>" + item.label + "</div><div class='v_address_auto'>" + item.add + "</div>" ).appendTo( ul );
};
```

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

your code will become like this

```
$("#venueName").autocomplete({
minLength: 3,
source: function(request, response) {

var city_lat = $('#city_lat').val();
var city_lon = $('#city_lon').val();

request.call = "auto_poi_ugc";
request.cityid = $('#eventCityId').val();
request.lat = city_lat;
request.lon = city_lon;

setTimeout(function() {
  ajax_req = $.ajax({
    url: "/ajaxcalls",
    dataType: "json",
    data: request,
    success: function( data ) {    
        data.splice(venue_limit,data.length);
        response( data );
    }
  });
  }, 700);
},
select: function(event, ui) {

    if(ui.item.value == "Loading..."){
      return false;
    }
    if(ajax_req != undefined)
    {
        ajax_req.abort();
    }
    if(ui.item.value != '')
    {
        $('#venue_latitude').val(ui.item.latitude);
        $('#venue_longitude').val(ui.item.longitude);
        $('#primus_id').val(ui.item.id);
        $('#event_venue_add').val(ui.item.add);
    }
 },
search: function(event, ui) {
    if($(this).hasClass('error-border')){
        $(this).removeClass('error-border');
    }
},
}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    if(item.add == undefined){
        item.add = "";
    }
    return $( "<li>" ).append( "<div>" + item.label + "</div><div class='v_address_auto'>" + item.add + "</div>" ).appendTo( ul );
};
```

Comment: You save a lot of my time. Thanks. works like charm.